# How to set parameters for test runner in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, nose, doctest

I'm new to PyCharm. How do I set [options for nosetests](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/doctests.html#options) when running [doctests from PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-doctest.html)? In Eclipse PyDev, this setting is under `Window > Preferences > PyDev > PyUnit`; I select the "Nose test runner" and set "Parameters for test runner" as follows:

```
--verbosity 0
--with-doctest
--doctest-tests
--doctest-options=+ELLIPSIS,+NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
```

Any help on doing the same in PyCharm is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Run > Edit Configurations`, which will open a window as shown below.

[image: Test Runner Configuration with PyCharm]

click on the green `+` button on the top left to add a configuration. Select Python tests then Nosetests.

Select the test scope using the radio button and fill up the relevant input boxes.

check the `Params` checkbox and in the input box next to `Params` is where you enter the parameters. enter them separated with a space, as you would do with a terminal. Now click `OK`

You can have multiple test configurations. To remove a configuration, use the red `-` button.

[image: Test Runner Selection with PyCharm]

now select the configuration you wish to run and press the green run button.

PS: Invalid configurations show a cross mark on the configuration icon.

Comment: It seems I am required to fill in the "Script:" field in your first screenshot. So, do I really have to make a separate configuration for every script, or every folder I want to apply this to? In any case, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome,  you may select `All in folder` and choose test directory .

Comment: Yeah, I saw. But then I must limit it to a specific _folder_... I was hoping to set these options as projectwide defaults, similar to a [nose.cfg](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) file (which seems not to be respected by the nosetests runner, unless I'm missing something).

Comment: I got so frustrated by making a separate run configuration for each file that I ended up hacking `helpers/pycharm/docrunner.py`, in `DocTestRunner.__run`
from `self.optionflags = original_optionflags` to `self.optionflags = original_optionflags | doctest.ELLIPSIS | doctest.NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE`. Ugly hack, but works for me. Now I can right-click any file and choose 'Run doctests in <filename>', with ellipsis and normalized whitespace.

Comment: @JonOlavVik That is not the way to run your tests. For your case, I'd create a nose configuration file as stated [here](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). Would you got to `File > Settings > Tools > Python Integrated Tools` and configure **nosetests**  as your test runner. Configurations are useful when you have to configure different configuration, in your case the configuration is same. I can't comment more on `nosetests` more because I'm not into nosetests and  `py.test` is my choice of test runner.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "That is not the way to run your tests" (except of course I shouldn't hack PyCharm files). Shouldn't right-click offer to apply the default test runner to a file, as in "Run doctests in <filename>"? Also confusing: 1) I set nosetests as default test runner, but see no right-click command to "Run nosetests in <filename>" and noserunner.py is not run. 2) `Run>Edit conf..>Defaults>Python tests` has a "Params" entry for Nosetests but not Doctests (where `-o ELLIPSIS -o NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE` would solve my issue).

Comment: I finally got it working. Maybe the key was to right-click the root source directory and `Mark directory as > sources root`. After that, the directory got a "Run nosetests in..." right-click menu item, which obeys the parameters I set in `Run > Edit configurations > Defaults > Python tests > Nosetests > Params`. Thank you so much for your help!